# iOS7 StatusBar using PhoneGap Build: set background color or text color

Tags: phonegap-build, ios7-statusbar

I know variations of this question have been asked dozens of times, but I haven't yet found one that addresses this combination: I want to be able to see a non-overlapping statusbar on iOS 7, using Adobe's Phonegap Build.

I have added the PhoneGap Statusbar plugin to my config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" version="1.1.0" />

<feature name="StatusBar">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
</feature>
```

This causes a black statusbar to appear correctly non-overlapping my site, but the text is (presumably) black, because I can't see it.

I have removed the `ios-statusbarstyle` preference from config.xml for good measure, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

The [plugin page](https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin) mentions that the config.xml options are not supported by PhoeGap build, so I tried to use the StatusBar javascript object. This is my complete index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

      function onLoad() {
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      }

      function onDeviceReady() {
        StatusBar.show();
        StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
        StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#C8DB2F");
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
    Test.
  </body>
</html>
```

but the backgroundColorByHexString() function does nothing and, in fact, there appears to be no StatusBar object at all -- this is confirmed by using PhoneGap Build's debug window, and because any JS that I try to put after those lines will not be executed, so presumably it is throwing an error.

Any thoughts on how to set either the statusbar background color or the text color? Do I have to use CLI instead of PhoneGapBuild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be too late for this... but I used your exact code and it worked for my app on phonegap build. I used this plugin instead.

`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.4" />`

and this to call the onDeviceReady function:

```
// wait for phonegap to be ready
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, referencing the correct plugin (org.apache.cordova instead of com.phonegap) solved it for me.

Comment: I wasn't having the same issue as the OP--my issues were with Ionic + Phonegap Build and not being able to control the status bar at all. Everything started working after I switched to the Cordova status bar plugin instead of the Phonegap plugin. This was just the tip I needed--thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the JS works when testing with [PhoneGap Developer App](http://app.phonegap.com/) but not with iOS emulator (i.e. when running `cordova emulate ios` from command line). Testing further, it seems the `deviceready` event doesn't fire at all when in iOS emulator.

Googling for "phonegap deviceready not fired" gives me similar error reports, albeit they all got mystically resolved, usually by reinstalling or fixing a typo.

One tangentially useful [answer pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736705/216129) the problem may lie in plugins; File plugin in particular. I didn't use the File plugin, but I checked the emulator's system.log, which gave me some errors relating to plugins:

```
Sep 12 10:26:58 username.local MyApp[8218] <Warning>: ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
[…]
Sep 12 10:26:58 username.local MyApp[8218] <Warning>: ERROR: Plugin 'Device' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
```

So I removed all the projects' plugins and then re-added them. I checked the versions before and after re-install and while the versions were identical:

```
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.10 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.11 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.9 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.7 "StatusBar"
```

Running the emulator again, the `deviceready` event got fired and status bar color changed!

---

**So, to sum up:** what plugins do you use and have you tried re-installing them?