# Cordova 3.5 deviceready event not fired after 5 seconds

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I recently upgraded my cordova app from cordova v2.9 to v3.5.0. After adding plugins from command-line, I imported my app to eclipse so that I can test on an android device. But, when I run the app, I see below logcat message:

```
07-08 11:24:03.359: I/Web Console(1500): deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova/cordova.js:1154

07-08 11:24:03.359: D/CordovaLog(1500): file:///android_asset/www/cordova/cordova.js: Line 1147 : Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady

07-08 11:24:03.359: I/Web Console(1500): Channel not fired: onFileSystemPathsReady at file:///android_asset/www/cordova/cordova.js:1147
```

According to **[Cordova Device ready doc](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)**, I had to bind `deviceready` inside `document.ready()`. It did not fire. Also tried binding it outside `document.ready()` according to some answers on SO. Still no luck. Can someone help me out???

**Device ready event binding**

```
function cordovaInit() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
}
```

I call `cordovaInit()` from `onload()` of body element like below:

```
<body onload="cordovaInit()">
```

The deviceready issue is gone now, but I am getting a Nullpointer Exception as below:

```
07-08 18:58:40.750: W/System.err(6670): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 18:58:40.750: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.LocalFilesystem.filesystemPathForURL(LocalFilesystem.java:67)
07-08 18:58:40.750: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.LocalFilesystem.getFileForLocalURL(LocalFilesystem.java:189)
07-08 18:58:40.750: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.getFile(FileUtils.java:749)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$5(FileUtils.java:742)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$16.run(FileUtils.java:397)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$23.run(FileUtils.java:525)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-08 18:58:40.760: W/System.err(6670):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Can you please post your code.

Comment: which part of the code you want? the code where I bind the deviceready event??

Comment: Yes, the code where you bind the deviceready event

Comment: edited the question and added code to bind `deviceready` event

Comment: did you add the `device` plugin? and did you re-build the application after?

Comment: Have you added any plugin?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Yes I did.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas Yes..but all those plugins I added through command line

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438087/cordova-file-plugin-never-becomes-ready-in-android

Comment: @SiddharthVyas You think the issue is file plugin?

Comment: @Rajesh : Yes. Uninstall the plugin and try with the link I provided.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas ok i will try and post the response here

Comment: @SiddharthVyas I used the files from the link, still same issue

Comment: @DawsonLoudon added the nullpointer exception stack trace

Comment: @SiddharthVyas added the nullpointer exception stack trace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56970/discussion-between-rajesh-and-siddharth-vyas).

Answer (score 2):

Same issue. Try to remove/update the File plugin, (org.apache.cordova.file)
 it's worked for me.
OnFileSystemReady is an event of that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Something else I found, try adding a sdcard to your emulator

I found my initial error was the file plugin was not being allowed to access a file space, this was because it didn't exist in the emulator, I added an external card to the emulator definition and hey presto it worked

Answer (score 0):

Did solve the same issue by uninstalling cordova.file plugin (and all plaugins that using it), uninstall platform, upgrade cordova to v4 and install all plugins back

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add I encountered this issue today with cordova 4.0.0 
I suspect this happens with more than just the File plugin because my problem was with Network information plugin (org.apache.cordova.network-information)

Back story: I had copied the project to a new folder and copied over the `plugins/` directory (I knew not to copy `platforms` from a previous mistake). This made it so the app was loading in chrome correctly and building correctly but showing a white screen on my device. Debugging by going to `chrome://inspect/#devices` and looking at console logs I saw that it was because the device ready event was not firing after 5 seconds.

Fix: I removed the plugins with `cordova plugin remove org.apache.cordova.network-information` and re-added it with `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information`